# JQuery: How to pass PHP data from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As for my HTML code is

```
<div class="right">
      <h2>Product Detail</h2>
      <div  id="righttop"></div>
      <button id="Add">Add</button>
</div>

<div  class="rightbot">
    <h2>Shopping Car</h2>
    <div id="rightbot"></div>
</div>
```

And the PHP is

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"products");
$sql="SELECT product_id, product_name, unit_price, unit_quantity, in_stock FROM products WHERE product_id = '".$productid."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>";
echo "<th>Product Name</th>";
echo "<th>Unit Price</th>";
echo "<th>Unit Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>In Stock</th>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr  id='detail'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['unit_price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['unit_quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['in_stock'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo $_POST['detail'];
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

`div#righttop` is changed by another button.

How can I pass the current content from `div#righttop` to `div#rightbot`?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to transfer the contents of `righttop` to `rightbot`, here is a way. On click of the button, before changing anything in `righttop`, do this:

```
$('#rightbot').html($('#righttop').html());
```

Comment: It works, but it replace the old content all the way. What I want is like a list that it cankeep adding new content to the list. Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: @waynecen -- Can you include all the relevant code in your question? It is hard to understand how the entire flow works. My current code takes whatever in the div `righttop` and writes it into the div `rightbot`.